# How to find previous element from $(this)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, selector

How to get the value of the `$(.subname)` when clicked on .bigadminbutton - function updateSub(). Tried everything (all combinations of prev, sibiling, parent, children, find...) but without any success. I am losing way too much time on this simple thing.

```
<div class='subdiv'>
     <input type='text' class='subname' value='Prva' />
     <a class="bigAdminButton"  href="#" onclick="updateSub()">
        <span class="bigAdminButtonText adminButtonText btnFix">Update</span>
     </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Forgot to tell that i have a lot of .subdiv's and a lot of bigadminbuttons as well... So $('subname').val() wont work for this one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your code so you don't have to use onclick to pass parameters. In general it's not a good idea to use pure event handlers and mix it with jQuery. jQuery makes sure that you get the best cross browser event handling possible. Note the data-id element. Instead of using the onclick handler to pass information you can declare a "data-*" attribute on the html tag to attach metadata information to it and then access that information from within the jQuery event handler.

```
<div class='subdiv'>
     <input type='text' class='subname' value='Prva' />
     <a class="bigAdminButton"  href="#" data-id="1">
        <span class="bigAdminButtonText adminButtonText btnFix">Update</span>
     </a>
</div>
```

Then the event handler can get the id as follows:

```
$("a.bigAdminButton").click(function () {    
     var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
     alert(id + ": " + $(this).siblings('.subname').val());
});
```

jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/cgencer/eU8d9/9/

You can also use `$(this).prev()` for the code above but that is more sensitive, in the case that you would add another element in between or change the order of the elements.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eU8d9/4/ i need it like this , cause i need to pass the parameter... but somehow its not working... I already tried that many times but nothing....

Comment: @user855705, I updated the answer with a different approach for you to pass parameters.

Comment: YOU ARE THE KING!!! I was missing document.ready thats why i didnt get anything alerted!!! THANK YOU ALL GUYS!

Comment: @user855705, you can just put your code in $(function () { //your code }); as a shortcut. good luck with jquery! :)

Answer (score 2):

I guess I'm not sure why [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) isn't working. It seems to here:

```
function updateSub (el) {
    alert(el.prev('input.subname').val());
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UQBrp/

Whoops. Forgot to mention I am passing `$(this)` to the function.

```
<div>
  <input type='text' class='subname' value='Prva0' />
  <div class='subdiv'>
     <input type='text' class='subname' value='Prva1' />
     <a class="bigAdminButton"  href="#" onclick="updateSub($(this))">
        <span class="bigAdminButtonText adminButtonText btnFix">Update</span>
     </a>
  </div>
  <div class='subdiv'>
     <input type='text' class='subname' value='Prva2' />
     <a class="bigAdminButton"  href="#" onclick="updateSub($(this))">
        <span class="bigAdminButtonText adminButtonText btnFix">Update</span>
     </a>
  </div>
  <div class='subdiv'>
     <input type='text' class='subname' value='Prva3' />
     <a class="bigAdminButton"  href="#" onclick="updateSub($(this))">
        <span class="bigAdminButtonText adminButtonText btnFix">Update</span>
     </a>
  </div>
  <div class='subdiv'>
     <input type='text' class='subname' value='Prva4' />
     <a class="bigAdminButton"  href="#" onclick="updateSub($(this))">
        <span class="bigAdminButtonText adminButtonText btnFix">Update</span>
     </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UQBrp/1/

And just passing `this` to the `updateSub()` function, with the `$()` in the function:

```
function updateSub (el) {
    alert($(el).prev('input.subname').val());
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UQBrp/3/

Comment: yep, prev() definitely works according to the markup and goals the OP specified. no idea where the confusion is...

Comment: To each their own. The question was how to find the adjacent previous element, not an argument about the best practices of onclick. How do I know the OP isn't inheriting a huge codebase with lots of inline event handlers and will not bother to replace them all even if I harangue them about it?

Answer (score 1):

I dont really understand why you mix up jQuery with javascript..if you use jQuery then do jQuery al the way. Why would you use "onclick" while you could have done this:

```
$('.bigAdminButton').click(function(){
    var x = $(this).prev('.subname').val();
    alert(x);//"Prva"
})
```

The above example worked just fine in js fiddle. [here is the link](http://jsfiddle.net/mYgdR/). Dont confuse yourself by mixing everything up. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.bigAdminButton').live('click', function () {
    alert($('input.subname').val());
});
```

If this is a repeated block of code where those classes are used again you could use:

```
$('a.bigAdminButton').live('click', function () {
    alert($(this).parent().find('input').val());
});
```

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle that seems to be working on my end: http://jsfiddle.net/3BUsk/

Answer (score 0):

```
alert($(this).parent().closest('.subname').val());
```

Comment: Isn't `.bigAdminButton`'s parent the `div` and not the input?

Comment: I don't think this will work either: It will find the immediate parent and then the find the closest element with class `subname` up the DOM...

Comment: yep, it means that      <input type='text' class='subname' value='Prva' />

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a.bigAdminButton").click(function() {
    var subnameValue = $(".subname", $(this).parent()).val();
    // (rest of your function)
});
```

Comment: there could be multiple elements with .subname

Comment: Point. Corrected by evaluating the selector in context of link's parent.

Comment: If it proves cumbersome to access element by class, you might want to think of better way to identify your markup elements. Like using unambiguous `id`s, for example.